# How do I know which versions of dependencies my application supports?

Tags: python

So when developing an app, it's considered good practice to specify the  *minimal* (least restrictive) needed dependency versions in `setup.py`'s, `install_requires`. Well, how do I know which versions of my dependencies my project actually depends on?

Is there any way to automatically determine this? If not, is there maybe a nice way to test the upper and lower bounds of the dependency ranges I specify?

Ideally, I'd like to focus on actual development more than manually tracking every new version of my dependencies and sifting through release histories to find out when the features I used were first introduced.

Answer (score 1):

The "Correct" way would just be to keep track of what features you use in each dependency, and then the minimum versions for each would be the minimum version that has those features, or has some important update (security, speed, etc).

The "If it works, it works" way would be to write a script that brute forces the versions for each individual dependency to get a range for each by installing it and seeing if it works. You could probably do this easily using github actions (Although you'd have to pay if your repo is private)

Comment: The "correct" way seems to be an awful lot of manual work :/ Especially when you start scaling up to a decently large project with lots of potential dependencies.

Comment: I mean, yeah, pretty much. If you keep track over time then the workload is more distributed, but if you're doing it all at once then it's a pain. There are ways to cut corners; if you expect the project to be on up-to-date dependencies then you could just set the minimum version as whatever version you currently have. If you're writing a library for something like a secure SCIF where you don't have access to the latest libraries, then you could write your code around the versions you know are approved and set it to those.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify the minimum versions but you should be focusing on the better performing dependencies. Always keep this in mind.

If `minimal` means the number of dependencies, you can use a package such as `pipdeptree` which shows the dependency tree of installed libraries in your environment. You can just list the top level libraries in your requirements and the other dependencies will be installed alongside with those top libraries.

When you install that library and just type `pipdeptree` you will see a similar output as below:

```
python-gitlab==1.8.0
  - requests [required: >=2.4.2, installed: 2.22.0]
    - certifi [required: >=2017.4.17, installed: 2019.6.16]
    - chardet [required: >=3.0.2,<3.1.0, installed: 3.0.4]
    - idna [required: >=2.5,<2.9, installed: 2.8]
    - urllib3 [required: >=1.21.1,<1.26,!=1.25.1,!=1.25.0, installed: 1.25.3]
  - six [required: Any, installed: 1.11.0]
python-jenkins==1.7.0
  - multi-key-dict [required: Any, installed: 2.0.3]
  - pbr [required: >=0.8.2, installed: 1.10.0]
  - requests [required: Any, installed: 2.22.0]
    - certifi [required: >=2017.4.17, installed: 2019.6.16]
    - chardet [required: >=3.0.2,<3.1.0, installed: 3.0.4]
    - idna [required: >=2.5,<2.9, installed: 2.8]
    - urllib3 [required: >=1.21.1,<1.26,!=1.25.1,!=1.25.0, installed: 1.25.3]
  - six [required: >=1.3.0, installed: 1.11.0]
```

So your requirements can be something like:

```
python-gitlab==1.8.0
python-jenkins==1.7.0
```

If you meant to specify the minimum possible versions then I don't know.

Comment: I meant the latter (minimum possible versions). I edited my question for hopefully better clarity.

Comment: it's a hard one. you probably need to check each dependency's release history etc. but I'm sure there is a way. let's wait for the real savior